# Scheme Vector Syntax

Tags: function, vector, scheme

Am I using the bound "vector" function from scheme correctly here?

```
(define (zip2 list1 list2)
 (if (null? list1)
   '()
   (vector (vector (car list1) (car list2))
           (zip2 (cdr list1) (cdr list2)))))
```

Comment: This is probably an easy answer, but I have not worked with vectors before and need to use them for plotting something.

Comment: What is the intended result?

Comment: I am trying to "zip" list X and Y into a list of data points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the result is correct. If we run the procedure in the question, this is what we get:

```
(zip2 '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
=> '#(#(1 4) #(#(2 5) #(#(3 6) ())))
```

As you can see, there are vectors nested within vectors, deeper than they should. The problem with your solution is that you can't just replace `cons` with `vector` and expect that things will work the same; `cons` is fine for building a list as you go, adding one element at a time, but for building a vector you need to know all the elements beforehand, because you can't add elements after its creation.

I'd rather solve the problem in terms of the "normal" `zip` operation (the one that uses lists) and then convert the result to vectors:

```
(define (zip list1 list2)
  (map list list1 list2))

(zip '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
=> '((1 4) (2 5) (3 6))

(define (zip2 list1 list2)
  (list->vector
   (map list->vector (zip list1 list2))))

(zip2 '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
=> '#(#(1 4) #(2 5) #(3 6))
```

Or equivalently, but without using `zip` as part of the solution:

```
(define (zip2 list1 list2)
  (list->vector
   (map vector list1 list2)))

(zip2 '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
=> '#(#(1 4) #(2 5) #(3 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.  In your `if` statement the `consequent` returns a list whereas the `alternate` returns a vector.  That is unlikely to be correct.  For example:

```
> (zip2 '(a b) '(1 2))
#(#(a 1) #(#(b 2) ()))
```

You notice the `()` in there?  Not good...  But, depends on your exact problem and you've not really stated that.  The fix might be as simple as replacing `'()` with `'#()`

**[Edit] Now that we know your need**.  This gets you there:

```
(define (zip2 list1 list2)
  (map vector list1 list2))

> (zip2 '(10 20) '(1 2)) 
(#(10 1) #(20 2))
```

Comment: If I replace '() with #() would that eliminate () altogether?